# Request error on Flask

Tags: pythonanywhere

Trying to make a request from web App on Pythonanywhere (paid account) with a Flask. This works as needed on local PC, but receives an error on Pythonanywhere.

```
@app.route('/test/')
def test():
 url_cookies='https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/ru/pxc/offcontext/'
 headers = {'authority': 'www.phoenixcontact.com',  'method': 'GET','user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}
 requestCookies = requests.get(url_cookies,headers=headers)
 return 'Test'+requestCookies.text
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?   Your call to `requests.get` will return a `response` object.   You're calling that `requestCookies`, so it would be useful to know the values of `requestCookies.status_code` and `requestCookies.content`.

Comment: I got 504 error, and it seems like the site I trying to request just blocking any activity from pythonanywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`pythonanywhere` has a only allowed [limited webpages](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) to be scrapped with the free version. You can remove this restriction by upgrading to one of their premium plans.

You might consider using [FreeHosts](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FreeHosts) like OpenShift for hosting your app.

Comment: Don't think that's the issue here -- the poster says that he has a paid account.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that after answering the question. But didn't delete the answer as I thought that it might be informative to others.